# Crash in CFRelease when removing a range of objects from a mutable array

Tags: ios, memory, crash, nsmutablearray

One of our testers is reporting the following crash:

```
0 APP_NAME_WAS_HERE 0x00074892 testflight_backtrace + 158
1 APP_NAME_WAS_HERE 0x000754bc TFSignalHandler + 244
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x378ea7ec _sigtramp + 48
3 CoreFoundation 0x30ef42e6 CFRelease + 94
4 CoreFoundation 0x30f09a36 -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:] + 294
5 CoreFoundation 0x30f4a65e -[NSMutableArray removeObjectsInRange:] + 90
6 APP_NAME_WAS_HERE 0x000570ca -[StoryViewController rewindToChunkIndex:] + 558
7 APP_NAME_WAS_HERE 0x00057396 -[StoryViewController restartChapter] + 22
```

Unfortunately, we can't reproduce the crash - we're only getting crash log sent through via TestFlight.

We did receive debug logs to confirm that the `removeObjectsInRange` is definitely receiving a valid range for the `NSMutableArray` that is being acted upon. (besides, that would kick up an exception rather than raising a signal, right?)

My only thought is that the object is getting a double release, but I'm not sure how this is possible with ARC switched on?

Note that the objects being removed are `UIView` subclasses, and before-hand, some or all of them may have been removed from their superviews. So I wouldn't be surprised if they were released at this stage, I just don't understand why that's causing it to crash!

**EDIT**: In an attempt to verify that it's an over-released object, I artificially tried over-releasing an object (using `CFRelease(__bridge (CFTypeRef) obj)` to force release in ARC environment) to see the type of crash log that it would produce. Unfortunately, it's a bit different, so perhaps it's not an over-release after all? Is it perhaps a scribble of some kind?

Here's what a definite over-release looks like:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x369c732c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36c20208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36c19298 abort + 88
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36bd437a free + 374
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x375e4d72 object_dispose + 14
5   CoreFoundation                  0x362e9618 -[NSObject dealloc] + 76
6   UIKit                           0x310323a8 -[UIView dealloc] + 620
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x375e416e _objc_rootRelease + 30
8   CoreFoundation                  0x362dc2e0 CFRelease + 88
9   APP_NAME_WAS_HERE                   0x000cea98 -[StoryViewController rewindToChunkIndex:] (StoryViewController.m:584)
```

Here's what an over-release crash log looks like:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fix for the problem was to turn the compiler's optimization level down to `None [-O0]` from the default setting of `Fastest, Smallest [-Os]` in the target's build setting (set in release only).

I'm not sure whether it's simply sidestepping the problem or whether there's actually a bug in the compiler, but there you go. And it explains why only testers were getting it.

Comment: I do not think that you have found your problem. You could create a category for NSObject and override retain and release to log every retain and release. This way you can see where the error is coming from.

Comment: that's just luck, the optimizer will change absolutely nothing about  doubly freed objects.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the stack trace, the crash occurs not because of wrong index, but because of a over-release of the objects.

NSArray sends a retain message when you add an object and a release message when you remove an object. Apparently, that release is crashing.

This means, you are over-releasing the object you added to your array.

**Update**

Are your sub-views strongly owned? Is your ownership modifier "strong" or "weak" or unsafe_unretained? Even in ARC, there can be unbalanced calls to retain if you don't "own" your variables properly. For example, since you are manually adding and removing views into another array, you should "own" it. Remove from superview will send a release to the view and addSubview will send a retain. When you build your views using XIB, the XIB loading mechanism uses the property'w ownership modifier and bump up the retain count accordingly when it adds it to the view (StoryViewController.view). Since XIB loading mechanism added it to subviews, you shouldn't unload it. If you want to unload it, you should "own" it by changing the property type of your subviews (outlets) to "strong", otherwise, you will end up messing the ownership.

Start thinking in terms of Object graphs and who owns what, when you write your ARC ownership modifiers. ARC is not like Garbage collection. Things like this will still happen :)

Comment: That was my conclusion too (as I mentioned in my original post albeit a bit too briefly!). So I guess the real question is: how is it possible to double-release an object with ARC?

Comment: That's interesting. Can you paste more code here? What is the object you are storing? Is it a CF object or NSObject?

Comment: It's an array of `UIViews` that I have just removed from their superview, so am cleaning up by removing from the array (which I need, partly because the ordering of them is important). There is too much related code to paste here, really, since the views are core to the app! Theoretically speaking, how could the ref count become unbalanced in _that_ direction? Some multithreading issue perhaps? And yet I have very very little multithreading in my app...

Comment: Updated my answer. I don't think it's a race issue.

Comment: Sorry Mugunth, I just found the problem and posted my answer. As you can see, it's very very weird! Thanks for valiantly trying though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing code, it's tough to say what the real problem is.  I'd bet its a case of something being over-released.  Remember, ARC does not apply to Core Foundation objects.

It's possible that you've assigned a property with an convenience constructor instead of with `alloc` and `init`.  Such objects are autoreleased and must be explicitly retained or they will be immediately deallocated in the following cycle.